# How can i keep global variables in dynamic library when using dlopen to reload it

Tags: linux, dlopen

I have tried to use `dlopen` to load a dynamic library with the flag `RTLD_NODELETE` in order to keep global variables and make sure they will not be reinitiated when next time i use `dlopen` to reload it.

But when I want to reload the library when some functions inside the library updated,
the `dlopen`(before reload i called the interface `dlclose`) seems to not work. The functions run with the same old code.

So i am confused now.

How can i keep global variables in dynamic library when using `dlopen` to reload it.
(Update the functions but leave the variables not changed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so i am confused now.

That's exactly what `RTLD_NODELETE` means: `dlclose` on such a library is (effectively) a no-op. Since the code *effectively* behaves as if `dlclose` has never been called, it's little wonder that subsequent `dlopen` doesn't reload the code either (it *also* becomes effectively a no-op).

> how can i keep global viriables in dynamic library when using dlopen to reload it. (update the functions but leave the virables not changed)

You can't.